# how to select AVG(:item1) with parameter in flask psql executing raw query.?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am getting error

> ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) function avg(unknown) is
>   not unique LINE 1: select AVG('item1') as total from items

whenever try to execute raw query in flask

```
engine.execute(text('select AVG(:item) as total from items'),item = item).fetchall()
```

turns out every time I get single quoted data from argument to function avg
which produces error. any solution??

Comment: What is the type of `item` variable?

Comment: decimal precision of postgres..

Comment: Is it [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal)? Please, post the output of `type(item)`.